# Margin-bottom not working, going beyond parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a text inside the `div` with class `message`, and I want to move the `div` to vertical center with respect to parent `div` with class `banner`.

Please refer the JsFiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/1rbhuwfs/

Whenever I try to set `margin-bottom`, it goes increasing beyond the parent `div` indefinitely, which I don't understand why. The parent `div` has `display: block` on it.

I prefer not to have any `position: absolute` in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below snippet, I have added

```
.banner > div {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

and removed `margin-bottom: 40px;` form `.message`.

```css
.banner {
  height: 100px;
  background-color:#4d1242;
  margin: 0 1px;
  display: block;
}

.banner > div {
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.img-1-holder {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.img1 {
  height: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.img-2-holder {
  display: inline-block;
}

.img2 {
  height: 100px;
}

.message {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="img-1-holder">
    <img class="img1" src="http://free-smiley-faces.de/images/free-animated-angry-smiley-animiert-wuetend_02_70x70.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    Some random text here
  </div>
  <div class="img-2-holder">
    <img class="img2" src="http://www.free-smiley-faces.de/Smiley-Faces/www.free-smiley-faces.de_smiley-face_03_100x100.gif">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check jsfiddle, put parent to `display:table` and child to `display: table-cell and vertical-align: middle`.

https://jsfiddle.net/ggq39acr/

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this too. https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

The solutions suggest in this link works in general ! :D

Answer (score 0):

One way to vertically center without `position: absolute` or using tables - and respecting your margin-bottom on image and text-div - is to use flexbox:

Add/change this:

```
.banner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5496yk1k/

Answer (score 0):

you can use flexbox [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n3vLbL3f/)

```
.banner {
 height: 100px;
 background-color:#4d1242;
 margin: 0 1px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
```

In this case you can remove the margins on

```
.img1 {
  height: 70px;
}   
.message {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to include a common class suppose `img-inline` with inline css properties and manage other css properties in your classes .img-1-holder,  .img-2-holder and .message

Here is a sample code for you. You can try it in your jsfiddle. Sorry I am not posting fiddle link here.

HTML CODE

```
<div class="banner">
  <div class="img-inline img-1-holder">
    <img class="img1" src="http://free-smiley-faces.de/images/free-animated-angry-smiley-animiert-wuetend_02_70x70.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="img-inline message">
    Some random text here
  </div>
  <div class="img-inline img-2-holder">
    <img class="img2" src="http://www.free-smiley-faces.de/Smiley-Faces/www.free-smiley-faces.de_smiley-face_03_100x100.gif">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.banner {
  height: 100px;
  background-color:#4d1242;
  margin: 0 1px;
  display: block;
}

.img-1-holder {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.img1 {
  height: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.img-2-holder {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.img2 {
  height: 100px;
}

.img-inline {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Hope this helps :)